# Trying to communicate between two servers

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, server, communication

So I'am struggling and don't really know what i need or want to use for this problem. The thing is I have javascript program that checks a database and sends it to another one, this program has alot of error handling.

On the other side i'am building a platform/dashboard that displays the errors. I've built it in PHP Laravel.

My question is:
How can i let my PHP dashboard "listen" to the javascript program and immediately when an error is thrown show it on the dashboard? While they are both running on different servers. I havent found a solution thus far

How would you approach this problem?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to build a server health monitoring tool with Laravel.

As you pointed out that they are two different servers, and different programming language environment, you may need to write a webhook (which is bascially an API) for the Javascript program to call.

Of course you will also need to catch the error in your Javascript system and calls a webhook to your Laravel system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Redis server.

Let your frontend javascript send the message to the Redis server. Write a little backend javascript that also connects to the Redis server to retrieve the messges.

PHP supports web sockets but is not always the best way to do it. If you use Laravel check out [Laravel Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting)